# Migrate question from ServerFault to Unix & Linux

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, flagging

When flagging a question on SF and selecting `It doesn't belong here` followed by `Off topic`, there are options to migrate to `meta`, `StackOverflow`, `SuperUsers` and `Webmasters` but not to `Unix&Linux`.  [this](https://serverfault.com/q/291776/86587) question is a good example of one which should be on Unix & Linux rather than ServerFault.

Am I missing a non-obvious way to migrate to U&L, or is this just not possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not possible to vote to migrate to U&L. You would have to flag and ask a moderator to do that move.

Answer (score 2):

We've recently added support for migrating to U&L by everyone with close privileges.

Answer (score 1):

I can only see moderator tools but there's a search box at the bottom that lets me move questions to any other SE site.

Comment: That search-box only shows up for mods, unfortunately. I checked on another SE site where I'm less spiffy.